# Angular preSelected options in custom component not showing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7, angular2-forms

I am trying to make a component that has a multi select dropdown. when I create an instance of this component i want to pass it a list of objects (in my case ICatagory) to show as the options. I also want to pass it a list of that same object(in my case ICatagory) as the preselected values.

So far I can pass it the list of objects and it will show it as the options, I am also able to pass it the preSelected values I want. however even though I can pass the preSelected, it does not show these values as selected.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aryu5y

This is the stackblitz i made to clarify. 
NOTE: when it loads there is nothing selected. I want the preSelected values to be selected on creation.

still somewhat new to Angular so forgive any anti convention patterns you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, I was able to figure it out.

there is something called [compareWith] that goes in your

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpzg9s

^^^stack blitz with solution.^^^

code diffrence. 
in my-drop-down.html
i added :

```
 [compareWith]="byId"
```

into the mat-select

in my-drop-down.ts
i added :

```
byId(obj1,obj2){
 if(obj1 != undefined && obj2 != undefined){
    return obj1.id === obj2.id;
  }
}
```

this was able to preSelect the options as objects.

if anyone has a better answer im open ears.